# Unable to send message in a fetched channel | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Purpose:** To message the guild owner and then create an invite and then send an invite to a specified channel.

**Code**

```
client.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.
    console.log(``);
    console.log(greenBright(`[GUILD JOINED] ${guild.name} | [ID] ${guild.id} | [ (+) MEMBERCOUNT: ${guild.memberCount}]`));
    console.log(``);

    const Owner = guild.ownerID;
    const fetchOwner = client.users.fetch(Owner);
    const InviteLogGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("761134473395306507")
    const InviteLogChannel = InviteLogGuild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === "803512574573543454");
    const getChennel = guild.channels.cache.first();

    (await fetchOwner).send(`Thank you for allowing lovell to  be added to your server, ${guild.name}, ${(await fetchOwner).username} !\nPrefix:\`${prefix}\`\nAll commands are displayed by saying \`${prefix}help\`\nFeel free to join lovell server: ${MainServer}`)
        .then(console.log(cyanBright(`[GUILD OWNER MESSAGED]`)))
        .catch(() => {
            console.error(redBright(`[GUILD OWNER MESSAGE DEINIED]`));
        });

    if (!getChennel) {
        return console.error(redBright('[CHANNEL COULD NOT BE FETCHED]'));
    } else {
        console.log(yellow('[CHANNEL FETCHED]'))
    }

    const link = getChennel.createInvite({
        unique: true,
        maxAge: 0,
        temporary: false,
        maxUses: 100
    })

    if (!link) {
        return console.log(redBright(`[INVITE FAILED]`));
    } else {
        console.log(blueBright(`[INVITE INITIATED]`));
    }

    if (!InviteLogGuild) {
        console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`))
    } else if (InviteLogGuild || !InviteLogChannel) {
        console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD IDENTIFIED | CHANNEL UNIDENTIFIED]\n`))
    } else if (!InviteLogChannel) {
        console.error(red(`\n[LOG CHANNEL NOT PRESENT]\n`));
    } else if (InviteLogChannel) {
        console.log(cyanBright(`[LOGGING INVITE]`));
        const LogChannel = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`New Guild Joined:`)
            .setDescription(`**Guild Name:** ${guild.name} \n\n**MemberCount:** ${guild.memberCount} \n\n**Onwer:** \`${(await fetchOwner).tag}\` \n\n**Invite Link:** ${(await link).url}`)
            .setThumbnail(`${guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
        InviteLogChannel.send(LogChannel);
        console.log(cyan(`[INVITE LOGGED]\n`));
    }

});
```

**Output/Error:**

```
[GUILD JOINED] Ghoulish Hangout | [ID] 618894612769275959 | [ (+) MEMBERCOUNT: 23]

[GUILD OWNER MESSAGED]
[CHANNEL FETCHED]
[INVITE INITIATED]

[LOG GUILD IDENTIFIED | CHANNEL UNIDENTIFIED] <---- Error
```

*Error can come along with:*

`(node:12052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel`

I have tried multiple ways to get the discord channel but it wont send the message or recognise the channel. Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Are you sure the IDs are correct?

Comment: Yes I am very sure

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why this worked but I took out my message commmand out of the if statements and it worked.

```
    if (!InviteLogGuild) {
        return console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`));
    } else if (InviteLogGuild) {
        console.log(greenBright(`[LOG GUILD IDENTIFIED]`));
    } else if (!InviteLogChannel) {
        return console.error(red(`\n[LOG CHANNEL NOT PRESENT]\n`));
    } else if (InviteLogChannel) {
        console.log(cyanBright(`[LOG CHANNEL IDENTIFIED]`));
    } 

    console.log(cyanBright(`[LOGGING INVITE]`));
    const SendMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`New Guild Joined:`)
        .setDescription(`**Guild Name:** ${guild.name} \n\n**MemberCount:** ${guild.memberCount} \n\n**Onwer:** \`${(await fetchOwner).tag}\` \n\n**Invite Link:** ${(await link).url}`)
        .setThumbnail(`${guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
    InviteLogChannel.send(SendMessage);
    console.log(cyan(`[INVITE LOGGED]\n`));
```

**Result:**

```
[GUILD JOINED] test | [ID] 2389372187328783 | [ (+) MEMBERCOUNT: 9]

[GUILD OWNER MESSAGED]
[CHANNEL FETCHED]
[INVITE INITIATED]
[LOG GUILD IDENTIFIED]
[LOGGING INVITE]
[INVITE LOGGED]
```

If someone could explain why this is, please feel free !

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Your if statements are wrong:

```js
if (!InviteLogGuild) {
  console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`))
} else if (InviteLogGuild || !InviteLogChannel) {
```

This is wrong, it will always enter this case, because you are checking if the InviteLogGuild is defined *or* the InviteLogChannel is undefined. Since the first case already checks for the InviteLogGuild to be defined, this will always return `true`. For it to work properly you'd have to change it to this:

```js
if (!InviteLogGuild) {
  console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`))
} else if (InviteLogGuild && !InviteLogChannel) {
```

But you can remove the `&&` completely, since the first case already checks if the InviteLogGuild is defined:

```js
if (!InviteLogGuild) {
  console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`))
} else if (!InviteLogChannel) {
```

If you take these things into account your final "if-chain" will look like this (and work):

```js
if (!InviteLogGuild) {
  console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD NOT IDENTIFIED]\n`));
} else if (!InviteLogChannel) {
  console.error(red(`\n[LOG GUILD IDENTIFIED | CHANNEL UNIDENTIFIED]\n`));
} else {
  console.log(cyanBright(`[LOGGING INVITE]`));
  const LogChannel = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`New Guild Joined:`)
    .setDescription(`**Guild Name:** ${guild.name} \n\n**MemberCount:** ${guild.memberCount} \n\n**Onwer:** \`${(await fetchOwner).tag}\` \n\n**Invite Link:** ${(await link).url}`)
    .setThumbnail(`${guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
  InviteLogChannel.send(LogChannel);
  console.log(cyan(`[INVITE LOGGED]\n`));
}
```

To avoid these sort of problems I would suggest you switch to using TypeScript or start using ESLint, which can advise you of unnecessary checks.

**Old Answer**

Try using `guild.channels.resolve(channelId)` and `client.guilds.resolve(guildId)` instead of using the cache. It might be that the channel hasn't been loaded into the cache yet and can't be found.

Comment: The same error still occurs. I've tried a different channel ID and it still the same error ;(